# Error: Unable to run ccollabgui

Tags: perforce, code-collaborator

After installing CodeCollab on OS X 10.6, I get `Error: Unable to run ccollabgui` when I try to add a new code review from `P4V`.

Strange but google was not able to find any match for the search :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I you receive this error just go to `p4v` `Tools->Manage Custom Tools` and select `Code Collaborator - Add to Review->Edit`.

Now change the application from `ccollabgui` to `/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub`.

Comment: For Windows Users, it's likely the path you need is C:\Program Files\Collaborator Client\ccollabgui.exe

Answer (score 2):

I received this error because I installed by ccollab in a non-standard location (not /Applications/ccollab_client)

[remove any already installed ccollab p4 custom tools if installed]

To fix, in p4v Tools|Manage Custom Tools|Select "SmartBear - Add to Review".  Click edit.  In the edit box called "Application", adjust the path to the correct path for your install.

Answer (score 1):

My issue had something to do with perforce. I updated Code Collaborator to a newer version and it installed the `Add to Review` tool in perforce. When I tried to run it I got the error above.

When I looked at the old tool that had previously been added I noticed one difference. The Arguments had `--p4 /usr/local/bin/p4` while the newer one didn't. When I added this it worked fine.

Comment: After trying everything, this solution finally worked. Thanks Man!!

Answer (score 0):

- To fix, in p4v Tools|Manage Custom Tools|Select "SmartBear - Add to Review".
- Click edit.

In the edit box called "Application" point to proper like below:

```
/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

In the edit box called "Arguments" point to proper like below:

```
--p4 /usr/local/bin/p4 --pause-on-error --scm perforce --p4port $p --p4user $u --p4client "emptyArgumentPrefix $c emptyArgumentSuffix" addchangelist ask %C
```